# require command issue in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a library in my project.When I want to use this with this code:

```
require('../Plugin/Utils/DateTimeUtil.php');
```

it says no such file exists. my cakephp 1s 2.3 what should I do?

Comment: Reading the documentation helps. You need to include the plugin - properly. And use App::import - properly - to make the class available. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html I also suspect that this is not a well defined plugin, as the class should be in a packaged subfolder inside the plugin root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Routing in cakephp is different from pure php.I had something like this.At first you should find the path Plugin folder with this code

```
$pluginPath = App::path('Plugin');
```

Then It returns an array which contains the plugin folder's path in 0 index.So you should the returned value like blow:

```
require($pluginPath[0] . 'Utils' . DS . 'DateTimeUtil.php');
```

You can use slash instead of DS. DS is DIRECTORY_SEPRATOR.